# Prewritten input in python

Tags: python, input, editing

Actually very simple but cant't find an answer.

I have a var `cmd` and want to let the user edit it before execution, without having to retype the command again.

```
cmd = "printf magic"
cmd = raw_input("Edit ur stuff: ")  <- print me cmd to stdin
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but did you try `cmd = raw_input("Edit ur stuff: {}".format(cmd))`?

Comment: Thanks alot, was exactly what I was looking for.